# Update textbox in UserControl from another UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I hava a MasterPage with 2 UserControls. When something happens in UserControl1.ascx, it has to update a TextBox in UserControl2.ascx.

**I tried this inside UserControl1.ascx, but no success:**

```
UserControl userControl = (UserControl)LoadControl("UserControl2.ascx");
var txt = (TextBox) userControl.FindControl("txtTest");
txt.Text = "Hello world";
```

Thanks for all help :)

Answer (score 0):

The `LoadControl` is load a new control that is not exist on page...

Lets see this example.
You have a master page that has 2 User Controls.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc1:WebUserControl ID="WebUserControl1" runat="server" />
        <br /><br />
        <uc2:WebUserControl ID="WebUserControl2" runat="server" />
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnOk" Text="ok" OnClick="btnOk_Click" />
    </div>    
</form>
```

and on code behind this

```
protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebUserControl1.TextOnMe = WebUserControl2.TextOnMe;
}
```

Now the user controls have this on html

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtText"></asp:TextBox>
```

and on code behind you get and set the Text like that on code behind

```
public string TextOnMe
{
    get
    {
        return txtText.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        txtText.Text = value;
    }
}
```

One Similar Answer
[ASP.NET MasterPage only control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768256/asp-net-masterpage-only-control/31783277#31783277)